# For multi-photo upload, how do I get it using API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I was trying to get the photos from facebook using the graph api, however, it seems like it will not include theose multi-photo upload images.

I have use graph api explorer to check, I put down

```
/<album id>/photos
```

It seems only retrieve the single photos and does not show the multi-photo upload images in the list.

How do I retrieve those multi-photo upload images using graph api?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the Graph which I won't deny is a bit limited compared to most. FB Graph api is a one to one upload. In order to upload multiple files you have to come up with a logic that suits your apps needs. Essentially building your own "queue" like logic so one photo will send after the other after the other.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my question is not about uploading, is about getting the images.

Answer (score 0):

`Session.openActiveSession()` only get the basic permissions such as "**user_about_me**", "**basic_info**" and "**user_photos**". To prove this, you could get the permissions from access token via `Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions()`.

Thus, if you want to show multi-photo upload, you need to request additional permission "**user_status**". Below is the sample code, it works for me.

```
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        //callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("user_photos","user_status");
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(PictureStreamMainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS));

                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mMeId = user.getId();
                    }
                  });                   
            }
        }
    });
```